# why we cannot use differential to prove jacobian transformation in double integral?

Tags: jacobian

example if we have cylindrical coordinates :
$x = r \ cos(\theta)$
$y = r \ sin(\theta)$
if we treated x as function of $r$ and $\theta$ then:

$dx = \partial x / \partial r\ *\ dr\ + \partial x/ \partial \theta\ * \ d\theta$

$dy = \partial y / \partial r\ *\ dr\ + \partial y/ \partial \theta\ * \ d\theta$

why we cannot use multiplication as $dxdy = (\partial y / \partial r\ *\ dr\ + \partial y/ \partial \theta\ * \ d\theta)*(\partial x / \partial r\ *\ dr\ + \partial x/ \partial \theta\ * \ d\theta)$

Comment: The short answer is that such "differentials" are not real numbers, so they do not obey the same arithmetic which real numbers follow. Therefore, since they aren't real numbers, there is actually no reason to even expect such "naive multiplication" to give the right answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it. Anyway, you have to use the **wedge product** (a.k.a. the **exterior product**). See here, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2296042/1242

Comment: sorry sir but what is exterior product belong to , i mean what is the math branch the contain or  study this type of product